# $X$ is the vector space $C[0,1]$ with the norm $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$, and $M=\{f\in X:f(0)=0\}$, show that $M$ is not closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my question:

Let $X$ be the vector space $C[0,1]$ with the norm $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$. Let

$$M=\{f\in X:f(0)=0\}$$

Show that $M$ is not closed. Show that the “quotient norm" $inf\{\|f-m\|_1:m\in M\}$ is not a norm on $X/M$.

Here is what I have:

For the closure, I am trying to find a function $f$ such that a sequence $\{f_n\}\in M$ which converges to $f$, but $f\notin M$. This would mean that for any $n$, $f_n(0)=0$ but $f(0)\neq 0$. I cannot seem to find such an $f_n$ and $f$.

As for the quotient norm not being a norm on $X/M$, I believe this follows from $M$ not being closed, as with quotient norms, $\|x-M\|=0$ if and only if $x\in M$.

So any suggestions on finding the $f$? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to show $M$ is open or $M$ is not closed; they're not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: @SimonS I want to show that it is not closed - I thought that they were the same.

Comment: $[0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is neither open nor closed under the usual metric. (And I see you've edited the title to take out open; makes sense.)

Answer (score 1):

$M$ is not closed:

Look at the sequence
$$
f_n(x) = \min(1, nx)
$$
and check that $f_n\to 1$ for the norm $\| .\|$.

Comment: I think you mean to say $f_n \rightarrow 1$, the constant function.

Comment: @SimonS indeed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As for the "quotient norm", have a look at mookid's counter-example and see if you can modify it to force a violation of one of the norm axioms. I'd aim to show that $$\| [f] \|_{\hbox{am I a norm?}} = 0  \ \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ \  f = 0$$ 
is violated.